# JS - Limit function execution to once a second

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, lodash

### Question

My context:

- JS with ES6
- [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.14) library.
- jQuery
- Cordova
- SAPUI5
- Android

I would like to know if there is any way to limit the execution of a function to once every x milliseconds. For example, a function on a button to prevent user spamming it and make bad calls.

I saw that [Lodash provides a method](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.14#once) to execute a function only once but is not limited on time so this doesn't works for my case.

### Solution Example

Thanks to [backtick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11751077/backtick)

```
var antiSpamLog = _.throttle(console.log, 2000, { 'trailing': false })
antiSpamLog("Can't spam this")
//> Can't spam this
antiSpamLog("Can't spam this")
antiSpamLog("Can't spam this")
antiSpamLog("Can't spam this")
//> Can't spam this
antiSpamLog("Can't spam this")
...
```

Comment: [`_.debounce`](https://underscorejs.org/#debounce), [`_.throttle`](https://underscorejs.org/#throttle).

Comment: This is not a duplicate of a question about debounce. Debouncing doesn't limit execution to once every N milliseconds.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ckfvaxL1/2/ check this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lodash provides a [`throttle` function](https://lodash.com/docs/#throttle) that does what you want.